# why "to sleep or lie on your back" but not "to sleep or lie with your back on the floor"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

[In the dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/back_1?q=back)

> Do you **sleep on your back** or your front?

---

[In the dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/back)

> He **lay on his back** and gazed at the ceiling.

I am a bit confused because we say "**sleep or lie on the floor**". **How can you sleep or lie on your own back?**

You can say, "**I lie on my boyfriend's back**" or "**I sleep or lie with my back on the floor**"

don't understand the usage of the preposition "**on**"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply put, it is just idiomatic to say that. "On" can be used this way, to refer to the part of your body that is in contact with a surface:

> - "I've been on my feet all day"
> - "He is standing on his head"
> - "He is lying on his back".
> - "I fell and landed on my nose".

The statement that you are "lying on the bed" is about your *location*, whereas "lying on your back" is about your body's position.

It might also be worth noting that, idiomatically, people sleep *in* a bed, not usually *on* a bed. The first refers to getting under the covers, and when people do say "on" a bed it usually means there are no covers, or that the subject is lying on top of them.

In a similar way, we say people swim, or float *on* their back or front; and likewise, "in the water" and "on the water" would imply different things.

Comment: We stand on our feet or legs, too.